# Css - backdrop-filter removing element from page

Tags: css

I have a div with the following css:

```css
.my-div-class {
    background-color: rgba(229, 231, 235, 0.95);
    /* backdrop-filter: blur(2em); */
    max-height: 65px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 24px;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
```

And I discovered that using it with chrome 108 and scrolling down, if I return to that div, it would be hidden. If you click anywhere to debug it, the div will appear again.

The only way to avoid it was removing the backdrop-filter.

Am I missing something here?

Discovered that removing the backdrop-filter, the problem would disappear.